# Hiking in the area around Quebec City

Tags: canada, hiking, itineraries, maps, quebec

I've decided to go spend 2 weeks in Quebec with my wife this summer.

Our plan for now is to

- spend a few days in Montreal (where our plane lands, coming from France)
- spend a few days in Quebec City
- rent a car and spend a week exploring Quebec's surrounding, maybe towards the north and Tadoussac, probably hiking a little in the mountains
- go back to Montreal (and take the plane)

I'd like to know where I can find hiking maps and topos for the region between Quebec City and Tadoussac. Is it possible to walk about everywhere in the mountains or are there many restricted areas ?

Any advice regarding small hiking trips in this region welcome !

Comment: Welcome to Travel SE! This sounds somewhat broad, since you're asking about itinerary, accommodation, transportation, maps, etc, all at once. Consider making this more specific, perhaps by splitting some topics to separate questions. (For example, "how to best go without car from Montreal to Quebec City" sounds like a fine stand-alone question to me!)

Comment: Would Travel SE enjoy 4 questions at the same time from me ?

Comment: I splitted it in 2 questions. I removed the other questions. See http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/8023/how-to-best-go-without-car-from-montreal-to-quebec-city

Comment: I don't think asking a bunch of questions (at the same time) is a problem, as long as they are on-topic, specific enough and "answerable". In fact, we [want](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/726/evangelising-time) lots of (good) questions here :-)

Comment: Ok, I'll see how that turns for the two first questions before spamming the site...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know that the question is bit old but I feel my answer can be useful for other users.

Since you are willing to go as far as Tadoussac,  I will recommend two other parks:

1. [Parc national des grands jardins](http://www.sepaq.com/pq/grj/index.dot?language_id=1) (2h15 from Quebec-City)
2. [Parc national des hautes  gorges de la rivière Malbaie](http://www.sepaq.com/pq/hgo/) (2h30 from Quebec-City)

I will recommend the `Pioui` trail at the Grand Jardins Park and `l’acropole des draveurs` trail at the hautes gorges de la rivière Malbaie.

**Last but not least**:  Jacques-Cartier is nice and close to Quebec but I feel  Jacques-Cartier is better suited for water activities (kayaking or fishing). Furthermore, unlike the two parks above, I will not consider Jacques-Cartier in my top 5 parks in Quebec. 
Nerveless, if you wish to go hiking to Jacques-Cartier, I will recommend the following hiking trail:

- Des loups
- Scotora

Since pictures speaks louder than words, I uploaded some pictures.

**Parc des grands jardins:**
[image: Parc des grands Jardins]
**Parc des hautes gorges de la rivière Malbaie:**
[image: Parc des hautes gorges de la rivière Malbaie]
**Parc Jacques-Cartier - Des loups trail:**
[image: Des loups]
**Parc Jacques-Cartier - Scotora  trail:**
[image: Scotora]

Comment: Hey, yes it's old and I had quite forgotten this question. I can confirm those are good advices as I did almost everything you suggested (apart Jacques-Cartier). I'll add that swimming in a quiet bay of the Saguenay river is very cool too (and cold, yes).

Answer (score 5):

Only thirty minutes outside of Quebec City there are scenic hiking trails where you feel like you are miles away from civilization. The hiking trails at Jacques-Cartier National Park range from trails for the most experienced hikers to climb to the top of the mountain.

Jacques-Cartier National Park is located just thirty minutes north of Quebec City. It is a part of the Laurentides Wildlife Reserve and has 100km of hiking trails with some linking to the National Hiking Trail.