# How to travel from Montreal to Quebec City without a car?

Tags: transportation, montreal, quebec

This is related to [Hiking around Quebec City](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/8022/hiking-around-quebec-city)

As I'll spend a few days in Montreal, then a few days in Quebec, I'd like to avoid renting a car just to go from one town to the other one. What's the most convenient (travelling with my wife and big backpacks)?

**EDIT** : viarail's web site doesn't seem to be able to manage online payments with visa card (no information given by the site on failure). Is somebody aware of a workaround to pay for train from another country ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have no first-hand experience, but taking the [**train**](http://www.viarail.ca/en/explore-our-destinations/trains/ontario-and-quebec/montreal-quebec-city) looks like a nice option.

The trip takes slightly more than **3 hours**, and quoting Via Rail's schedule, there are "five departures every weekday from both Montréal and Québec City, and three departures on Saturdays and Sundays".

It looks like [baggage allowance](http://www.viarail.ca/en/trains/ontario-and-quebec/montreal-quebec-city/useful-info) won't be a problem either.

Regarding the **price**: one-way trip in economy class costs C$85, booked the same day. But if you book in advance, you can get it for as little as $51 on a restricted "escape" fare. More details when you click "Compare" on the booking page. [Prices updated for 2017.]

**Edit**: The **bus** option doesn't look bad either. It also takes a bit more than 3 hours from downtown to downtown, and (with a quick look) costs about C$50 if booked the same day. [2012 price.]

One advantage with buses is that there *tons* of departures every day. For example, [Orléans Express](https://www.orleansexpress.com/), one of the major operators, has some 20 daily departures between 06:00 and 23:00.

To me, both train and bus definitely seem viable options—I guess it's a matter of taste which one you should choose.

Comment: Thanks for the details. I'll wait a little for other answers or comments before I accept but I wont forget

Comment: The train is much nicer than the bus. And VIA 1 includes free wifi, nice hot meal, free alcohol etc. There are some very inexpensive options if you buy far enough in advance.

Comment: As a bonus the train station in Quebec is walking distance from downtown (though with a steep hill to climb).

Comment: I do have first hand experience, and the train is a nice option. The only thing I would add is I would recommend buying food at the station rather than on the train.

Comment: It's worth noting that the Montreal-Quebec City train only allows carry-on sized luggage (full-size suitcases are prohibited).

Comment: @200_success: Good point. To be very exact, [on this train you can take](http://www.viarail.ca/en/trains/ontario-and-quebec/montreal-quebec-city/useful-info) **two** pieces with maximum dimensions of 66 x 46 x 23 cm and max weight of 23 kg. So nothing as limited as carry-ons in air travel, and a *lot* of luggage actually (46 kg), but full-size suitcases are indeed off limits.

Comment: Seats on VIA trains are way more comfortable than any bus seats.  There are new luggage restrictions: either one 40-lb. carry-on piece and one 25-lb. - or three 25-lb. pieces.  The 25-lb pieces must be like the airline carry-ons, the 40-lb. piece must be within the size limit (the sum of dimensions < 62 inches).

Comment: I also think the scenery from train is better (I won't lie, the road on the highway 20 is boring).

Comment: @KateGregory only in 1st class are there such amenities.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero that's why my comment started "And VIA 1 includes" -- they may have renamed their product in the intervening 7 years, but I think people will figure it out.

Comment: @KateGregory If one can get a cheap 1st class fare then the train *definitely* worth it.  The meal is quite acceptable as a matter of fact.

Answer (score 2):

There is at least one bus every hour, operated by Orléans Express.  At peak times the busses will leave as soon as they fill up, often more than once during an hour.  The busses run along Hwy 20, the main highway between Quebec and Montreal.  As far as I remember there’s free wifi on the bus.

Watch for two sub-stations: normally busses pick up/disembark passengers at Longueuil, just outside Montreal island, and in Ste-Foy, now amalgamated with Quebec City.  At peak times when busses are full they may skip Longueuil or Ste-Foy and go direct downtown to downtown.

The trains are more comfortable (more legroom) but there are only a few each day.  There is also free wifi.  Unfortunately they often run late so not recommended if you have a tight appointment at either end.