# Where is this beach in Prince Edward Island?

Tags: canada, identify-this, prince-edward-island

The photographer [lists the location as Covehead](https://www.flickr.com/photos/117449597@N03/39690149963/), but the place name on the right (under the map) states 'Bay Fortune'. Can anyone pls locate it on Google Maps?

I'm curious if this beach [looks better after being edited than in real life](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/76348/92533)...

[image]

Comment: I would guess that real life doesn't look quite as good as this photo - no disrespect implied or intended. This looks very much like an HDR photo which intensifies all the colors, and the water is absolutely mirror smooth, which strikes me as unusual, even in a bay.

Comment: Yes. I haven't been to this beach specifically, but Cavendish was definitely more of a Martian-esque dull pink, not the maroon shown here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is Covehead, PEI. You are looking south, as in [this](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Covehead,+PE+C0A+1P0,+Canada/@46.4096626,-63.1308449,423a,35y,155.44h,65.57t/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x4b5fb4327e49f3d5:0x374cf5ed3655775f!8m2!3d46.392333!4d-63.121015) angle from Google Maps - see the peninsula jutting out in the middle and the hill in the background.

By contrast, [Bay Fortune](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Bay+Fortune,+PE+C0A+2B0,+Canada/@46.3336757,-62.3656749,2203m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x4b5e1144b8d9a531:0x6199d52e175f7613!8m2!3d46.336971!4d-62.369277) doesn't look anything like this - there is only a tiny fork as the river goes upstream (very small, not nearly as big as the one above), and there are farm fields adjacent to the water (which are not present in the photo above).

Also note the visible sand beaches in the Covehead location, which don't really show up in Bay Fortune. Bay Fortune also lacks hills - it's all low-lying agricultural land. Also, the sun is on the right in the photo above - if this was a shot taken looking northwest up Bay Fortune, the sun would be in the northern part of the sky, which is impossible this far north, and also, as Henning Makholm mentioned, this far south of the polar regions.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more accurate to say that 46° north is _not far enough_ north to see the sun low in the northern sky? The farther you get from the equator, the _more_ of the horizon is between the celestial tropics (and therefore potential directions for a sunrise or sunset).

Comment: @HenningMakholm I was thinking more by comparison to the tropics, but yes you are also right.